# sidekiq worker rails argument error for one of two workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actionmailer, sidekiq, worker

I have a rails app using sidekiq w/ redis for mailers. I have 2 workers, but for one of them I get wrong number of arguments error (ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 2) ) and I don't know why since the other one, which is basically the same, works perfectly. Here is the code/explanation for both: Contactmailer w/ Postmanworker is the working one which sends out an email when sby submits a contact form; Taskmailer w/ Taskcreatorworker gives the error, which sends out an email when a task gets created. I've already tried with different number of arguments, as I see I have 6 args at the moment but still gives the 5 for 2 error => Prior to sidekiq, taskmailer worked as well. For first I tried to pass only 2 args @task.id and @current_user and I could call all the 6 variables that can be found in task_created.html.erb. Since then I've tried different kind and number of args. As you see below, at the moment I try to give all the 6 variables in controller and mailer as well exactly as they are called. I also show the user.rb since model is a bit tricky.

Since the contact mailer works perfectly both in dev/prod env, I likely made a mistake in the code below and it's not a server/installation problem.

tasks_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @task = Task.new(task_params))
  if @task.save
    h = JSON.generate( {'task_assigner_first_name' => @current_user.profile.first_name,
                      'task_assigner_last_name' => @current_user.profile.last_name,
                      'task_executor_first_name' => @task.executor.profile.first_name,
                      'task_executor_email' => @task.executor.email,
                      'task_executor_id' => @task.executor_id,
                      'task_id' => @task.id
                       } )
    TaskcreatorWorker.perform_async(h, 5)
    #TaskMailer.task_created(current_user, @task).deliver_later
    flash[:success] = "Task saved!"
    redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user)
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end

private
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:executor_id, :name, :content, :deadline).merge(assigner_id: current_user.id)
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
    h = JSON.generate({ 'name' => params[:contact][:name],
                      'email' => params[:contact][:email],
                      'comment' => params[:contact][:comment] })

    PostmanWorker.perform_async(h, 5)
    #ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, comment).deliver_later
    flash[:success] = "Message sent."
    redirect_to new_contact_path
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Error occured."
    render action: :new
  end
end

private
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comment)
end
```

taskcreator_worker.rb

```
class TaskcreatorWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(h, count)
    h = JSON.load(h)
    TaskMailer.task_created(h['task_assigner_first_name'], h['task_assigner_last_name'], h['task_executor_first_name'], h['task_executor_email'], h['task_executor_id'], h['task_id']).deliver_later
  end
end
```

postman_worker.rb

```
class PostmanWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(h, count)
    h = JSON.load(h)
    ContactMailer.contact_email(h['name'],h['email'],h['comment']).deliver_later
  end 
end
```

task_mailer.rb

```
class TaskMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def task_created(task_assigner_first_name, task_assigner_last_name, task_executor_first_name, task_executor_email, task_executor_id, task_id) 
    @task.assigner.profile.first_name = task_assigner_first_name
    @task.assigner.profile.last_name = task_assigner_last_name
    @task.executor.profile.first_name = task_executor_first_name
    @task.executor.email = task_executor_email
    @task.executor_id = task_executor_id
    @task.id = task_id

    mail(from: 'faskyn@gmail.com',
         to: "#{task.executor.email}",
         subject: "[Faskyn] New task/favor from #{task.assigner.profile.first_name} #{task.assigner.profile.last_name}"
         )
  end
end
```

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: 'faskyn@gmail.com'

  def contact_email(name, email, content)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @content = content

    mail(from: email, subject: 'Contact form message')
  end
end
```

task_created.html.erb

```
<p>Hi <%= @task.executor.profile.first_name%>,</p>

<p><%= @current_user.profile.first_name %> <%= @current_user.profile.last_name %> just sent you a new task/favor.</p>

<p>You can check it out <%= link_to "here", user_task_url(@task.executor_id, @task.id) %>.</p>

<p>Cheers,<br />Faskyn Team</p>
```

contact_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>You have received a message from the site's contact form, from <%= "#{ @name }, #{ @email}." %></p>
   <p><%= @comment %></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

user.rb

```
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
```

error message from sidekiq log:

```
2015-09-28T12:48:33.600Z 20264 TID-outp8berw TaskcreatorWorker JID-a0816ab8d1881e81c58569d2 INFO: start
2015-09-28T12:48:33.633Z 20264 TID-outp8berw TaskcreatorWorker JID-a0816ab8d1881e81c58569d2 INFO: fail: 0.033 sec
2015-09-28T12:48:33.635Z 20264 TID-outp8berw WARN: {"class"=>"TaskcreatorWorker", "args"=>["{\"task_assigner_first_name\":\"Szilard\",\"task_assigner_last_name\":\"Hungarian\",\"task_executor_first_name\":\"Andrew\",\"task_executor_email\":\"szilard.magyar@speaktoit.com\",\"task_executor_id\":3,\"task_id\":82}", 5], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"a0816ab8d1881e81c58569d2", "created_at"=>1443439028.7889678, "enqueued_at"=>1443444513.5961752, "error_message"=>"wrong number of arguments (5 for 2)", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>1443439028.8198888, "retry_count"=>8, "retried_at"=>1443444513.632468}
2015-09-28T12:48:33.636Z 20264 TID-outp8berw WARN: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 2)
2015-09-28T12:48:33.636Z 20264 TID-outp8berw WARN: /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/app/mailers/task_mailer.rb:3:in `task_created'


2015-09-28T16:17:07.015Z 23136 TID-ow4vpw9ik TaskcreatorWorker JID-6cb35b9b42bebdbf128746c0 INFO: start
2015-09-28T16:17:08.178Z 23136 TID-ow4vpw9ik TaskcreatorWorker JID-6cb35b9b42bebdbf128746c0 INFO: fail: 1.163 sec
2015-09-28T16:17:08.180Z 23136 TID-ow4vpw9ik WARN: {"class"=>"TaskcreatorWorker", "args"=>["{\"task_assigner_first_name\":\"Szilard\",\"task_assigner_last_name\":\"Hungarian\",\"task_executor_first_name\":\"Peter\",\"task_executor_email\":\"szilard@api.ai\",\"task_executor_id\":2,\"task_id\":83}", 5], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"6cb35b9b42bebdbf128746c0", "created_at"=>1443456758.3800051, "enqueued_at"=>1443457026.97385, "error_message"=>"undefined method `assigner' for nil:NilClass", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>1443456758.398172, "retry_count"=>3, "retried_at"=>1443457028.177601}
2015-09-28T16:17:08.180Z 23136 TID-ow4vpw9ik WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `assigner' for nil:NilClass
2015-09-28T16:17:08.180Z 23136 TID-ow4vpw9ik WARN: /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/app/mailers/task_mailer.rb:4:in `task_created'
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of your error.

Comment: Do you need other logs as well?

Comment: The logs indicate that the error came from the method `TaskMailer#task_created` exactly. Your code examples show that the method indeed does expect more than 2 arguments. Therefore I conclude that the most likely solution is that you haven't restarted sidekiq in a while. Sidekiq caches code and it might have an old reference to `TaskMailer`.

Comment: Siim I restarted everytime when I changed something. I also restarted redis-server and webrick.

Comment: I will try again in 5mins and let you know the result.

Comment: Siim it looks like you were right. After restarting all the servers I got a new error message. I still don't get it.

Comment: You also don't need to JSON serialize the hash worker argument.  Sidekiq will serialize the hash for you.

Comment: Mike, can that cause the problem here, or it would just make it better? As I see I did the same in both cases, still just one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a reference to your `@task` instance variable that is not set when coming from sidekiq. You need to initialize your `@task` variable in the mailer method itself. Depending on the desired outcome, it can be done in several ways.

1. `@task = Task.new`

   Initialize a task and all the objects it needs (`assigner` and `executor`) and then give them the values passed in from your worker.
2. `@task = Task.find(task_id)`

   This is a better solution since then you don't need to pass all of parameters through sidekiq. Your task is already saved in the database, so just pass the id through and use it to find the task. It will have all the required data already.

tasks_controller.rb

```
    def create
      @user = current_user
      @task = Task.new(task_params)
      if @task.save
        TaskcreatorWorker.perform_async(@task.id, @user.id)
        flash[:success] = "Task saved!"
        redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user)
      else
        render action: :new
      end
    end
```

taskcreator_worker.rb

```
    class TaskcreatorWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker
    
      def perform(task_id, user_id) # Removed count since you weren't using it. Add it back if needed
        TaskMailer.task_created(
          Task.find(task_id),
          User.find(user_id)
        ).deliver_now # deliver_now since we're already in a sidekiq worker
      end
    end
```

task_mailer.rb

```
    class TaskMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      def task_created(task, user)
        # Initialize variables you use in your view
        @task = task
        @current_user = user
        mail(from: 'faskyn@gmail.com',
             to: "#{task.executor.email}",
             subject: "[Faskyn] New task/favor from "\
                      "#{task.assigner.profile.first_name} "\
                      "#{task.assigner.profile.last_name}"
        )
      end
    end
```

Comment: Siim, works perfectly. Thank you!  I'm pretty new to rails, sry for being so incompetent. Let me ask two last question since I'm still a little confused:   1. I followed this tut: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-2-mailer-with-sidekiq. Is this a good example according to you, or the JSON.generate is unnecessary? 2. Why did it work with my contactmailer and why didn't with the task? For my eyes these two are identical. Thx, in advance!

Comment: 1) I didn't see anything wrong with that tutorial on first glance. Sidekiq by default uses YAML to store data you put into it. JSON can be used to control the format of the data if you want to, but is not necessary.

2) In your other mailer you did not use any previously initialized variables. You assigned values to 3 new variables just as I did in my new answer. In your previous code you were referencing the `@task` variable that was not set.